# Why am I not getting a response in this Chrome extension message exchange?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension that requires jQuery (not too familiar with jQuery). I have some messages getting passed around, but at some point it stops working and I'm not sure why. Currently on manifest v2 but working on moving to manifest v3.

Here's the folder structure:

- chrome-extension

  - configs
  - dist
  - node_modules
  - src

    - css
    - js

      - internal

        - *functions.js*
      - *functions.js*
      - *jquery.js*
      - *product.js*
    - *manifest.json*
    - *popup.html*

When I reload the page, the extension runs this in product.js which passes a message

```
// product.js    

$(function(){
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: "getStatus"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response) //This response never happens
        if(response.status != 'true'){
          //do some stuff
          }
```

The message is received in functions.js

```
//functions.js    

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(request) //logs {method: 'getStatus'}
        console.log(sender) //logs info about the tab
        console.log(window.localStorage) //logs local storage
        if (request.method == "getStatus") {
          sendResponse({status: localStorage['opt-disable']}); //this sends nothing?
        } else {
          sendResponse({msg: "hello"}); //this is just a test
        }
    });
```

Back in product.js, there is no response. It seems like sendResponse in functions.js is sending a truthy/falsy value, and 'opt-disable' doesn't exist in localStorage so I would expect it to be falsy, but in the console log in product.js, nothing even shows up as a response. Why isn't the response sending?

Here is manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Chrome Assistant DEV",
  "short_name": "Chrome Assistant DEV",
  "description": "Dev Version",
  "version": "2.12.1",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "cookies",
    "identity",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "*://*/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/icon-128.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "img/icon-16.png",
    "32": "img/icon-32.png",
    "64": "img/icon-64.png",
    "128": "img/icon-128.png"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "js/jquery.js",
    "css/pagecss.css",
    "js/internal/gmail_libraries.js",
    "js/internal/gmail_functions.js",
    "pages/oauth2_success.html"
  ],
  "background": {
      "scripts": [
        "config.js",
        "js/jquery.js",
        "js/developer.js",
        "js/helperFn.js",
        "js/functions.js",
        "js/internal/functions.js",
        "js/internal/results.js"
      ]
   },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["config.js", "js/jquery.js", "js/product.js"]
    }
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",
  "commands": {
      "_execute_browser_action": {
         "suggested_key": {
            "default": "Alt+Shift+O"
         }
      },
   },
  "externally_connectable": {
    "ids": ["*"],
    "matches": [
      "https://mail.google.com/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm importing many of the scripts in popup.html as well, here's the head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: auto;">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="config.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/typeahead.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/helperFn.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/internal/functions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popup.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/rebrand_2018.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
  </head>
```

Comment: Show us manifest.json and how/where these scripts are defined.